# Links Contained in iframes do not do anything

Tags: javascript, css, html

So, on a webpage that I created, there are iframes loaded when you search something. However, when you click on a link within the iframe, it does not do anything. It worked recently, and I did not change anything, but now all of a sudden it does not work. I have set up a proprietary search [here](http://sun.iwu.edu/~mkelly1/). This specific one is for a used car search on CL. Search something and when the iframes load, the links do not work.

Thank You,

Mike

Comment: Please do not link to external code. Once that code moves, your question becomes useless to others. Post an example as part of your question.

Comment: Most of the links work just fine for me, it's only the result links that don't work by clicking them (though middle-clicking them does work and opens them in a new tab). Also I'd suggest making your search a little less big and giving more room to your iFrame since that's where your user will be spending most of their time.

Comment: try adding a target to the links. It will work for links wich are not working.

Comment: @Johannes That's the issue I am having, the CL links don't work

Answer (score 0):

When I try with Opera, I get an error saying "The website does not permit its content to be displayed in a frame. It must be displayed in a separate window."

If it worked until recently, my guess is this is a recent change in how the website works.
I don't think you can do anything about it, but tell your users they will need to open all links in new tabs.